# Same function returns different result when running in console or spec2

Tags: scala, base64, spec2

It's a very strange problem.

I have a simple class which can decode a base64 string and get the first part before the `:`:

```
import scala.util.{Success, Try}
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64

class IdDecoder {

  def decode(token: String): Option[String] = {
    if (token.isEmpty)
      None
    else
      Try(new String(Base64.decodeBase64(token.getBytes)).split(":")(0)) match {
        case Success(id) => Some(id)
        case _ => None
      }
  }

}
```

And define a method which decodes the string

```
object StrangeToken {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    decode()
  }

  def decode() = {
    val token = "InternalServerError"
    val Some(id) = (new IdDecoder).decode(token)
    println("### StrangeToken's id len:" + id.length)
    id.toCharArray.foreach(c => println(c.toInt))
    id
  }

}
```

### Running as plain code, id's length is 15

When I run it in sbt's console or in IDEA or in production, the result is:

```
### StrangeToken's id len:15
34
123
94
65533
118
65533
73
65533
65533
122
65533
43
0
0
0
```

### Running as spec2 test, id's length is 14

But when I run it in spec2, as:

```
"id decoder" should {
  "get decoded string whose length is 15" in {
    val id = StrangeToken.decode()
    id.length must be equalTo 15
  }
}
```

This test failed and the result is:

```
### StrangeToken's id len:14
34
123
94
198
118
8226
73
205
212
122
177
43
198
228
```

I'm not sure why the result is different in spec2.

Comment: Did you try to launch your tests with the sequential attribute?

Comment: I just run this single test when trying to identify this problem

Comment: why is token length different in each case?

Comment: That's my question too. First one is running in console/idea/production, second is running with spec2(by `sbt test`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happen to get 14 in my sbt console, where my sbt script specifies `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8`.

Your `new String(bytes)` uses the default encoding.  You can supply a charset to the constructor.

Second guess:

You have different versions of the -codec library in `Test` configuration and otherwise.

When I bump the version back to 1.1, I also get 15.

To be honest, that was going to be my second guess originally.  There is a lot of history in the -codec project, so incompatibilities or behavior changes are not amazing.  Presumably the behavior that elicits the number 14 is more conforming.

It's also not amazing that a "common" dependency appears twice in dependency trees.

Comment: I have `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8` in my sbt file too when I see this problem. I tried to specify the charset `new String(Base64.decodeBase64(token.getBytes), "UTF-8)`, but still get `15`

Comment: @Freewind Added the second guess. Forgive me for not bisecting for the version that changed the behavior.

Comment: your guess is correct! I just found in the functional code, it uses `codec-1.3`, but in the test, it uses `codec-1.6`. Now I declare it explicitly as `codec-1.9`, everything works well. Thank you!